# mysql GROUP_CONCAT(query)

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I'm trying to run a query that looks like:

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(vehicles.id)  
FROM                                                                
 vehicles                         
WHERE                                                               
 cars.id = vehicles.id
```

brings the right data:

```
1,2,3
```

However, now I want the brand name using GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(SELECT brand_name FROM brands WHERE vehicles.id = brand.id) 
FROM                                                                
 vehicles                         
WHERE                                                               
 vehicles.id = 100
```

so I can get `'Brand1', 'Brand2', 'Brand3'`

Comment: What is `WHERE cars.id = vehicles.id`? there is no `cars` in your query.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(brands.brand_name) 
FROM                                                                
 vehicles
 inner join brands on vehicles.id=brands.id 
 inner join cars on cars.id=vehicles.id                       
WHERE                                                               
 cars.id = vehicles.id
```